# Automatically data and wifi are being activated

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

few days ago my lg e420 with android 4.1.2 version had to be restored due to following few problems, firstly its data services and wifi settings get automatically activated. By this the battery life is rapidly decreased. When i switch them off by myself,all happens again by itself..is there any solutions,? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly and you are on the stock ROM, you should be able to fix it by going to `Settings>More>Mobile Networks` and disabling something called connections optimizer.